# MS Clarity does not show the full heatmaps of my site

Tags: heatmap, ms-clarity

I have installed the Clarity Script on several websites , so far so good , Clarity started collecting the login data on all websites correctly ,

however I noticed that on one of the sites when using the heat map , Clarity does not let me scroll the entire page , it gets stuck only at the beginning of the site.

I attach a printout of the example and I hope this verification.

[incomplete heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFYh8.jpg)

I have searched clarity documentation but I can't find an answer to this problem.

Comment: Update your post with the code you have tried.